# How to enumerate system restore points using WinAPI (not WMI)?

Tags: c++, winapi, system-restore, restore-points

Must work for WinXp - Vista - Windows 7

Comment: WMI should be available on the platforms that you require. It might be a problem with Win 2000 though.

Comment: @divo: System Restore does not exist on Windows 2000.

Comment: @SLaks: So even less reason not to use WMI ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having a short look at the [available documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378975%28VS.85%29.aspx) it seems that there is no way around WMI if you want to *list* existing restore points.

The Windows API only offers you functions for setting and removing restore points:

- [SRSetRestorePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378941(VS.85).aspx), and
- [SRRemoveRestorePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378934(VS.85).aspx)

MSDN also has [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408121%28VS.85%29.aspx) how to use these methods.

For listing the existing restore points you can use the VBScript sample code from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378951%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Note that the code needs elevation on Vista and above):

```
Set RPSet = GetObject("winmgmts:root/default").InstancesOf ("SystemRestore")
for each RP in RPSet
    wscript.Echo "Dir: RP" & RP.SequenceNumber & ", Name: " & RP.Description & ", Type: ", RP.RestorePointType & ", Time: " & RP.CreationTime
next
```